# How can I crop a specific area of an image using Python?

Tags: python, image-processing

[image]

This is an image containing some text, then a text box, then a Signature & after that a bottom line ending the picture.

[image] And the 2nd image is what I want as output using python.

I have several pictures like this, I want the same cropped output for all the images.

Here is what I tried:  I used pytesseract to OCR the image 1st to locate the text box determining that as starting point & thresholding to determine the endpoint of the signature area....then tried using OpenCV to crop that area & saving it in a local directory but the approach is not much promising.

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several relatively simple approaches you could try.

---

You could use `cv2.findContours()` to locate the two big black titles *"Additional Information"* and *"Signatures and Certifications"* and scale off their position to deduce where the signature is. Your intermediate image might be like this:

[image]

---

You could use *"Hit and Miss"* matching to locate the 4 corners of the box *"The IRS doesn't require your consent..."*.

---

You could do flood-fills in say, red, starting from white pixels near the centre of the image till you get a red box filled around the right size for the box *"The IRS doesn't require your consent..."*. Then scale from that.

[image]

---

You could do a flood-fill in black, starting 2/3 of the way down the image and half way across, then find the remaining white area which would be the box *"The IRS doesn't require..."*.

[image]

---

You could look for the large, empty white area below the signature (using summation across the rows) and scale off that. I am showing the summation across the rows to the right of the original image. You could invert first and look for black. Do the summation with:

```
rowTotals = np.sum(img, axis=1)
```

[image]